# Angular-block-ui does not work with the latest version of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to block the UI while loading content. I am using AngularJS 1.3.5.

I cannot seem to get [angular-block-ui](https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui) to work for me.

It says on the github page approx~ support version 1.2.4. Does anyone know why?

And can anybody recommend an equivalent library that I could use instead? Perhaps Toaster?

Comment: I have managed to get it to work with an older version of angular-block-ui. http://plnkr.co/edit/xBSFHdYwUosNPKu93QaL?p=info . I think I might just use Toaster instead because I would rather not tell bower explicitly which versions to get.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial pitfall for this not to work is forgetting to include the block ui css file.